# get array matches with json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have field in database with type json:

```
[{"id": "1"}, {"id": "2"}, {"id": "3"}]
```

and I need get matches in json with array `["1", "2"]` for at least one element.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get all rows from the table where the JSON column contains both both IDs? Btw: `["id : 1", id : 2"]` is invalid JSON - is that really your input? Or did you mean `[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]`?

Comment: yes, there is an error in the array. I want to get at least one match from an array in json. fixed the error

Comment: @СвятославМарюха: but `["id : 1", "id : 2"]` is not a valid JSON array, as explained by a_horse_with_no_name...

Comment: not written so my mistake

Comment: array - ["1", "2"], json - [{"id": "1"}, {"id": "2"}, {"id": "3"}]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select t.*
from the_table t
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(t.the_column) as x(item)
                join jsonb_array_elements_text('["1", "2"]') as e(id)
                  on x.item ->> 'id' = e.id);
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a21bb56ff4f81825e72d782175d48bd7)